# Do I need redux if I use redux-toolkit?

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I tried adding redux to my react-native project, but when using the createStore method of redux, VSCode told me that it was deprecated and I should use redux-toolkit instead. I added it to my project, but I wander if I can remus the `redux` package now when I have the `@reduxjs/toolkit` installed?

Answer (score 2):

`@reduxjs/toolkit` uses `redux` as a dependency package, so it has be installed, but don't use it in your code

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@reduxjs/toolkit?activeTab=dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Yes, part of the point of Redux Toolkit is that it already includes the `redux` core package automatically.  So, you don't have to list `redux` in your `package.json` - just `@reduxjs/toolkit`.

Comment: Should be removed from here as well then.
https://github.com/reduxjs/cra-template-redux/blob/master/package.json

Comment: Eh, sorta. That's the list of dependencies for _developing_ on the template package, not what actually gets installed for _users_ of the template. But sure, that could be removed.